# How to read an attribute of angular.element without knowing whether it has been prefixed with data- or x-data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I was wondering, whether there is a standard way to get an attribute from an angular element without knowing whether the attribute name has been prefixed with data- or x-data.

I've seen this code inside a directive:

```
el.attr('x-data-' + attr) || el.attr('data-' + attr) || el.attr(attr).
```

Is this the correct approach, or there is something more standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML
You can add attribute to element like data-*.(note:always prefix your attribute with data-)

```
<div data-tasktype = "somevalue"> </div>
```

In Js File
You can fetch the value of attribute like

```
 var val = element.data('tasktype');
```

(note:here prefixed part will be skipped.)
Browser:IE9 & above,chrome,etc.

If you are not sure about the browser or also not sure what would be the naming convention you are going to use for your attribute, you can go for

```
 el.attr('x-data-' + attr) || el.attr('data-' + attr) || el.attr(attr)
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is your own application that your directive will be used and if you know your browser versions well ahead (i.e. not the <= IE8) I would not bother the `data-` prefixes.

On the other hand if your are developing library of directives for others to use and you have no control of browsers or the HTML authors you should just use what you have.